# Is there a way to see all the photos of a portal all together?

Tags: ingress

Browsing through the photographs of a portal is somewhat cumbersome if the portal has many of them and you're looking for a specific one among them. Is there a way to see them en masse?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When viewing a portal with more than one photo, press on the portal photo in the portal window. This will open the portal detail view. In the portal detail view, press the button looking like a 3x2 squares matrix on the top right corner. This will open a gallery view containing all the photographs belonging to that portal. This gallery view button won't appear on portals with only one photo.

[image: Gallery Button]

[image: Gallery View]